# Table tr rowspan not fix in mozilla

Tags: html

https://codepen.io/Nobody-Mr/pen/abPJrEr?editors=1000

google chrome
[image]
Firefox

[image]

same code but Firefox extra gap create.
it's not solve to line height issue

Chrome

[image: chrome]

Firefox

[image]

Didn't see the glitch until I added a "rowspan" to the table. Problem appears on the latest Firefox and the latest Mozilla

```html
<table class="table " cellspacing="0" id="__load" style="width: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>আনন্দ পাঠ (বাংলা দ্রুত পঠন)</th>
      <th width="50%" style="text-align: right;">
        <i class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="__append_seed" data-sid="MQ==" data-cid="MQ==">Seed</i>
        <i class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="__append" data-sid="MQ==" data-cid="MQ==">Create</i>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="__tbody">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 10rem">অভিজ্ঞতা শিরোনাম </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;" width="20%">একক যোগ্যতা . </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word" width="5%">পারদর্শিতা সূচক (PI)নং.</td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="word-wrap: anywhere; border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;" width="20%">পারদর্শিতার সূচক</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
                <span>পারদর্শিতার মাত্রা</span>
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black">Action</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center;  border: 1px solid black  ">○</td>
              <td style="text-align: center;  border: 1px solid black  ">△</td>
              <td style="text-align: center;  border: 1px solid black  ">◻</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>`your text`
          <tbody>
            <tr class="__trash_17">
              <td rowspan="4" style="border: 1px solid black;text-align: left; vertical-align: top ">
                <span>7.2</span>
                <span>ভিভিন্ন ভিভিন্ন পরিস্থিতিতে রিস্থিতিতে যো যোগাযোগে যোগের অনুশসংক্ষিপ্ত কথোপকথন তৈরি করার কাজটি দলের সকল সদস্য মিলে আলোচনা করে প্রস্তুত করবে। ভূমিকাভিনয়ের কাজটি দলের সকলে মিলে বা মনোনীত কয়েকজন সদস্য মিলে উপস্থাপন করতে পারো।শীলনন করা</span>
              </td>
              <td rowspan="4" style="border: 1px solid black;text-align: left; vertical-align: top ">
                <span>সংক্ষিপ্ত কথোপকথন তৈরি করার কাজটি দলের সকল সদস্য মিলে আলোচনা করে প্রস্তুত করবে। ভূমিকাভিনয়ের কাজটি দলের সকলে মিলে বা মনোনীত কয়েকজন সদস্য মিলে উপস্থাপন করতে পারো।</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="__trash_17">
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="5%"> 7.2.1 </td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="20%"></td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Quisquam a</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Id quia ve</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Est dolore</td>
              <td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black">
                <i class="fa fa-circle btn btn-xs btn-primary __edit__ has-ripple" data-id="MTc="></i>
                <i class="fa fa-trash btn btn-xs btn-danger mt-1 __delete__" data-id="MTc="></i>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="__trash_17">
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="5%"> 7.2.2 </td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="20%"></td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Rerum ipsu</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Sit deseru</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Consequatu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="__trash_17">
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="5%"> 7.2.3 </td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="20%"></td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Ex adipisi</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Odit ad po</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Minima ali</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a proper snippet, Could you make a [mcve] - possibly with lorem ipsum instead of your native language?

Comment: You can't have every cell in a row span multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is structured wrong. The second `tbody` contains four rows, however you only want to display three. Considering that I actually think Firefox is doing the better job of rendering it, because it correctly is trying to render four rows.

You need to change both `rowspan="4"` in the first row to `"3"`, and merge the first and second row:

```html
<table class="table " cellspacing="0" id="__load" style="width: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>আনন্দ পাঠ (বাংলা দ্রুত পঠন)</th>
      <th width="50%" style="text-align: right;">
        <i class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="__append_seed" data-sid="MQ==" data-cid="MQ==">Seed</i>
        <i class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="__append" data-sid="MQ==" data-cid="MQ==">Create</i>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="__tbody">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 10rem">অভিজ্ঞতা শিরোনাম </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;" width="20%">একক যোগ্যতা . </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word" width="5%">পারদর্শিতা সূচক (PI)নং.</td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="word-wrap: anywhere; border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;" width="20%">পারদর্শিতার সূচক</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
                <span>পারদর্শিতার মাত্রা</span>
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black">Action</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center;  border: 1px solid black  ">○</td>
              <td style="text-align: center;  border: 1px solid black  ">△</td>
              <td style="text-align: center;  border: 1px solid black  ">◻</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>`your text`
          <tbody>
            <tr class="__trash_17">
              <td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;text-align: left; vertical-align: top ">
                <span>7.2</span>
                <span>ভিভিন্ন ভিভিন্ন পরিস্থিতিতে রিস্থিতিতে যো যোগাযোগে যোগের অনুশসংক্ষিপ্ত কথোপকথন তৈরি করার কাজটি দলের সকল সদস্য মিলে আলোচনা করে প্রস্তুত করবে। ভূমিকাভিনয়ের কাজটি দলের সকলে মিলে বা মনোনীত কয়েকজন সদস্য মিলে উপস্থাপন করতে পারো।শীলনন করা</span>
              </td>
              <td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black;text-align: left; vertical-align: top ">
                <span>সংক্ষিপ্ত কথোপকথন তৈরি করার কাজটি দলের সকল সদস্য মিলে আলোচনা করে প্রস্তুত করবে। ভূমিকাভিনয়ের কাজটি দলের সকলে মিলে বা মনোনীত কয়েকজন সদস্য মিলে উপস্থাপন করতে পারো।</span>
              </td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="5%"> 7.2.1 </td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="20%"></td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Quisquam a</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Id quia ve</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Est dolore</td>
              <td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black">
                <i class="fa fa-circle btn btn-xs btn-primary __edit__ has-ripple" data-id="MTc="></i>
                <i class="fa fa-trash btn btn-xs btn-danger mt-1 __delete__" data-id="MTc="></i>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="__trash_17">
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="5%"> 7.2.2 </td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="20%"></td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Rerum ipsu</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Sit deseru</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Consequatu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="__trash_17">
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="5%"> 7.2.3 </td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left" width="20%"></td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Ex adipisi</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Odit ad po</td>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Minima ali</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

BTW, as a general hint: move the styles to an external style sheet. Inline styles clutter up the code, which makes spotting errors more difficult.